# MongoDB connection security

Tags: mongodb, ssl, tls1.2

I'm having some mongodb connection securtity concerns for my env.

Here is my environment:

1. one ECS hosted on cloud that has a public IP but **no domain and no ssl certificate** neither.
2. installed mongodb service on this ECS that needs **username/password to authenticate**
3. only **specific IPs** in the whitelist can access the ECS/mongodb

I'm wondering if the data transfer between this mongodb and my local pc is safe or not?

Will the data be encrpyted **during the transmission** or just plain text so that everyone on the internet can catch and read it? (As I don't have https so it's not using TLS/SSL)

Can canyone explain the machanism or give some some doc links?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are vulnerable to an eavesdropping attack. HTTPS has nothing to do with this. Here is a doc link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-transport-encryption/

Answer (score 0):

As your not using SSL, your data on fly is not encrypted. You need to use TLS/SSL to encrypt the network transmission. You must have the TLS/SSL certificates as PEM files, which are concatenated certificate containers

In addition to encrypting connections, TLS/SSL allows for authentication using certificates, both for client authentication and for internal authentication of members of replica sets and sharded clusters